# React-Native-Maps: Not showing complete map

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, visual-studio-code

I am using react-native-maps and the version is "react-native-maps": "1.3.2". It is not showing map on the whole screen of the emulator rather shows incomplete map like this;

[image]

This is my code. Please guide if I need to do some styling for this ?

```
    import {ProgressSteps, ProgressStep} from 'react-native-progress-steps';
   import React from 'react';
   import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';

const RegistrationWizard = () => {
   return (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ProgressSteps>
    <ProgressStep label="First Step">
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Map View</Text>
        <Text>This is map</Text>
        <Text>This is map</Text>
        <Text>This is map</Text>

        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showsMyLocationButton={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />

       
      </View>
    </ProgressStep>
    <ProgressStep label="Second Step">
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>This is the content within step 2!</Text>
      </View>
    </ProgressStep>
    <ProgressStep label="Third Step">
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>This is the content within step 3!</Text>
      </View>
    </ProgressStep>
  </ProgressSteps>
</View>
 );
 };

  export default RegistrationWizard;
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
      ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
   height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
   width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
```

});

Comment: see here https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/map-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android device, you need to define the height of map parent component.

```js
 <View style={{alignItems: 'center',height:Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.7}}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          showsMyLocationButton={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        /> 
      </View>
```

Demo - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/a1e773